# Cannot resize image in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, resize

I just started programming a week or two ago, so I apologize for the potential terrible code, but I've been having a hard time figuring this one thing out.
I've managed to get the files to upload to the designated destination, but I just can't get the resize/image manipulation tool to work.

The code that's giving me the problem is the commented out section, and I've already made sure to give the folders the proper privileges. Any help would be outstanding.

I've also been curious about how I would use absolute paths for something like this:

```
function avatar_update() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './avatars/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width'] = '100';
    $config['max_height'] = '100';
    $config['file_name'] = time();

    $filename = $config['file_name'];

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $error);
        $this->load->view('General/header');
        $this->load->view('profile_view', $error);
        $this->load->view('General/footer');

    } else {
        // $this->load->library('image_lib');

        // $resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        // $resize['source_image'] = './avatars/'.$filename.'.jpg';
        // $resize['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        // $resize['create_thumb'] =TRUE;
        // $resize['width'] = 50;
        // $resize['height'] = 50;

        // $this->load->library('image_lib', $resize);

        // $this->image_lib->resize();

        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $avatar = array(
            'avatar' => $filename
        );

        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->update('users', $avatar);

        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $user_details = $query->row_array();

        }

        $this->session->set_userdata($user_details);

        $this->load->view('General/header');
        $this->load->view('profile_view');
        $this->load->view('General/footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: A description of "not working" would be really useful :)

Comment: The resized image just never shows up on the server :/.

Comment: Do I need to download the GD2 library or does it come with CI?

Comment: GD2 is an image library used for PHP. It's usually included with most PHP hosts, but you may want to try to run a "phpinfo()" to see if it's there.  
Also, you don't need to load the image_lib library twice. So you can get rid of the first one. I'm not sure if that helps with your problem or not.

Comment: So, you're definitely sure that the image has uploaded? As @TerryMatula says, you can get rid of the first time you load the image library. Have you tried wrapping the resize() function in a conditional and seeing if it throws out any errors? Use $this->image_lib->display_errors().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok to me (except for loading the image library twice!). Try adding a path for the new image into your config array.

```
$resize['new_image'] = '/path/to/new_image.jpg';
```

You shouldn't need it, but it might be worth a try! 
Also, as per my comment you should wrap the resize() function in conditionals so you can test and echo any errors.

PS. When you get more used to CI and the MVC model think about moving all your db logic to a model.

Comment: Lol, I thought they were two different libraries :O. Thanks for pointing that out, I ended up getting the resize to work and I've been slowly using models a lot more. Using models didn't make sense at the early stages, but makes a lot more sense now.